# Simple questions about the Jacobson Radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Questions:** [See below]
>
> $\rm\color{#c00}{(1)}$ What structure has $R/I$ when $I$ is a maximal *left* ideal? I know that if $I$ is a *bilateral* ideal then $R/I$ is a ring and, moreover, if $I$ is maximal then it is a field, in which case we get the simplicity of $R/I$.
>
> This question naturally gives rise to the second question.
>
> $\rm\color{#c00}{(2)}$ I know that if we define $J'(R)$ by changing the word *left* for the word *right* in $(\star)$, then $J(R)=J'(R)$ and the characterization $(\star\star)$ remains valid, with the word *left* changed for the word *right*. However, can we put the word *bilateral* instead of left or right in $(\star\star)$? In the French Wikipedia page [Radical de Jacobson](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_de_Jacobson), $J(R)$ seems to be defined exactly this way and the proof of $(\star\star\star)$ presented there seems to make more sense since in that case $R/I$ is a field as usual.

Define the *Jacobson radical* of a ring (with unity) $R$ by
$$
J(R):=\bigcap_{M\text{ a simple, left }R\text{-module}}\text{Ann}_R(M).\quad(\star)
$$
Then one can show
$$
J(R)=\bigcap_{I\text{ a maximal, left ideal of }R}I.\quad(\star\star)
$$
Next, in order to show the $[\Longleftarrow]$ part of
$$
r\in J(R)\iff\forall x\in R:1+xr\in R^{\times},\quad(\star\star\star)
$$
one proceeds by contradiction as follows:

**Proof of $[\Longleftarrow]$:** Suppose that for all $x\in R$ we have $1+xr\in R^{\times}$ but that there is a maximal left ideal $I$ of $R$ for which $r\not\in I$. $\rm\color{#c00}{(1)}$ Then $R/I$ is simple, hence $R\overline{r}=I\text{ or }R/I$. Since $r\not\in I$, $R\overline{r}=R/I$ and so there is an $x\in R$ such that $1+xr\in I$. But $1+xr$ is invertible, hence $1\in I$ and $I=R$ which contradicts the hypothesis that $I$ is maximal. $\blacksquare$

Comment: If this is your question: I do not believe that the intersection of all maximal two-sides ideals of $R$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$ in general. But if I remember it correctly, it is true when $R$ is Artinian. I do not know how you would define the annihilator of a two-sided $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What structure has R/I when I is a maximal left ideal?

The best we can say is that it is a left $R$ module and not necessarily anything more.

> moreover if $I$ is maximal then it is a field,

No, in general you will only get a simple ring.

> However, can we put the word bilateral instead of left or right in (⋆⋆)?

It will not yield the Jacobson radical. Let $R$ be the ring of linear transformations of a countable dimensional vector space. Then $R$ has exactly one nontrivial bilateral ideal: the set of transformations with finite dimensional range. However the whole ring is Von Neumann regular with Jacobson radical zero.

> In the French Wikipedia page Radical de Jacobson, J(R) seems to be defined exactly this way

I notice that the article says "le radical de Jacobson d'un anneau **commutatif** est..." Of course if the ring is commutative then we don't need left or right ideals anymore.